# Aws CDK : Api gateway, sagemaker integration, AWS Service of type SageMakerRuntime not supported error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker, aws-cdk

When I set the service as `SageMakerRuntime` or `SageMaker`, It throws the error `AWS Service of type SagemakerRuntime not supported (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException;` I couldn't find documentation on what are the supported service. However when set up the api gateway from console I see the option `SageMaker Runtime` and rest of the configuration works fine.

```
const integration = new AwsIntegration({
      service: "SageMakerRuntime",
      path: "endpoints/{endpointName}/invocations",
      integrationHttpMethod: "POST",
      options: {
        credentialsRole: Role.fromRoleArn(
          this,
          "Execution role",
          "<arn>"
        )
      }
    });
const postMethod = api.root
      .addResource(this.node.tryGetContext("serviceVersion"))
      .addResource("endpoints")
      .addResource("{endpointName}")
      .addResource("inferences")
      .addMethod("POST", integration);
```

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Runtime's service name in CDK is `runtime.sagemaker`. Pass that in for the service parameter and you should be good to go.

For CDK, the names of services use a different format than what's shown by `aws list-services`. I found this format here, under `ServiceName`:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sagemakerruntime/